# carrying custom wordpress query variable throughout session

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

I'm creating a wordpress site that needs to have two distinct versions. The changes in the two are only frontend, and will be very minimal so I don't want to create two separate sites.

Instead, I'd like to pass a query string along that dictates whether or not to serve the prop version.

People will access the prop site by going to http://example.com/?prop=1. Once they're there, I need that "prop=1" to be carried over when they click any link on the blog. I could do this by hand in all of the templates, taking all the links and making sure to append that query to them, but I'd like to do it in an automated way.

Basically, if that query var is there, carry it through to any links that person clicks on the site. If it's not, then serve regular links. I'm also open to using session variables, but someone should be able to visit the prop and regular sites at the same time in separate windows, so I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Session will work with seperate windows. It will not work with separate browsers. Also a session will end when the browser is closed. I personally would do this with a $_COOKIE`

Comment: use $_cookie like @Vector said or a constant on prop=1 and then check for if(isset... for instance

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to do this task? maybe you won't need to depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The client needs there to be a prop version of the site that is a bit different in the content it shows and the design. People will be brought to this prop site from external links, and once there, they should continue being served the prop version while following links on the site. That's essentially the functionality I need.

Comment: how exactly should I use $_cookie? I need to have it so if a user has the prop version open and they go to the url and remove /?prop=1, they are brought to the default version, same window and browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this solution - htaccess rewrite

or a redirect plug-in

basic idea will be using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}`

`The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.` - php.net 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

if the current request has `?prop=1` then it will append `?prop=1` to the end , else nothing happens.

once user enters `?prop=1` mode they won't be able to leave it unless `?prop=1` is removed

Comment: Trying to figure out how to do the RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}. I'm pretty unfamiliar with htaccess stuff. is that just checking where the person came from? or will it allow me to simply check to see if ?prop=1 is in the URL.

Comment: @user3465903 you will have to use regex to read the string if it includes `?prop=1` in them